# Inverse of a Linear transformation in complex analysis

Tags: complex-analysis, linear-transformations

I am given $T z= \frac{z+2}{z+3}$ , where $T_1$ is a linear transformation on the complex number $z$. I need to find its inverse $T^{-1}z$.

I considered a complex number $w =\frac{z+2}{z+3} $. This gives me $z = \frac{2-3w}{w-1} $.  So, the inverse linear transformation is $\frac{2-3z}{z-1}$.

Am I correct or is this a wrong way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, $S(z) = \frac{2-3z}{z-1}$ is the inverse mapping of $T(z) = \frac{z+2}{z+3}$.

Since a Möbiustransformation is uniquely determined by its values at
three different points in the extended complex plane, one quick method
to verify the result is to check that $S \circ T$ maps three different
points to itself, for example the points $-2$, $-3$ and $\infty$.

Generally, the inverse mapping of $T(z) = \frac{az+b}{cz+d}$
is $T^{-1}(z) = \frac{dz-b}{-cz+a}$ which corresponds to the rules
of inverting a 2-by-2 matrix.